# log4shell exploit for Redis server

Tags: redis, log4j

We are running redis server on EC2 instance.

i can see in many publications that Redis Server is vulnerable to the log4shell exploit, but can't see any documentation or any official about that.

What should I do in order to protect my redis server instance to be in-vulnerable for this exploit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redis Server does not use Java and is therefore not impacted by this vulnerability.

See more here: https://redis.com/security/notice-apache-log4j2-cve-2021-44228/